# What's happend with my chrome dev console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-console

Font weight & Font color looks very strange, how to remove font-weight: bold & set object property color to normal

[image]

1. I have not installed themes or modules
2. I disabled all extensions
3. I reset chrome settings
4. I rebooted my computer

but no effect

that is normal console

[image]

Comment: That looks like the default dark theme to me, and it doesn’t look bold either. Can you describe the differences?

Comment: object property color must be a violet and font weight looks like 400+

Answer (score 1):

[See This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z22lE.png)

**Look In The Image Above**

All you need to do is to open your developer console and then goto settings.
Then in the left top you will see Preferences>>Appearance>>Theme
Choose the Light Theme.

Comment: set a dark theme but nothing changed

object property color must be a violet and font weight looks like 400+

Comment: You should keep in mind that chrome has different settings for the chrome itself and different for developer console. you need to goto the developer console settings . I did it myself and its working fine. Remember Developer Console settings,... not in the chrome settings and not in chrome Customize..